# Replace elements that do not match a pattern

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I have the following matrix

```
mat={{0,a,b},{c,0,d},{0,0,e}}
```

I would like to replace the zero elements of it with 1 and the remaining with zero. The first step would be

```
mat/.{0->1}
```

However I have not idea how to use the replace operator /. for indicating all the elements that do not match a pattern.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: What type are the other elements ? Symbols ? Strings ? the pattern should be constructed to match those.

Comment: This will do if the other elements are Symbols. mat /. {0 -> 1, (x_Symbol /; x =!= List) -> 0} Can you guess why we need to exclude List in the pattern ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SetAttributes[rep, Listable]
rep[_] := 0
rep[0] := 1

rep @ mat
```

> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}

**Update**

This method can easily be extended by adding new rules to `rep`, f.e.:

```
rep[a_ /; MemberQ[{-t, t, -s, s}, a]] := a
```

Now

```
rep @ {{0, a12, s}, {a21, a22, -s}, {t, s, -t}}
```

> {{1, 0, s}, {0, 0, -s}, {t, s, -t}}

Comment: you can also do: `rep[a : -t | t | -s | s] := a`

Comment: Thanks, always nice to have `Alternatives` :)

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: You're welcome - and thanks for the accept

Answer (score 16):

```
Replace[mat, {0 -> 1, _ -> 0}, {2}]
(* or Replace[mat, {0 -> 1, Except[0] -> 0}, {2}] *)
```

> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}

Also

```
1 - Unitize @ ArrayComponents @ mat
```

> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}

And a variation of @Lotus's suggestion for `ReplaceAll`:

```
mat /. {0 -> 1, Except[List, _Symbol] -> 0}
```

> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}

**Update:** *Can this method be generalised to a matrix made of mixed symbols: e.g. {{a11, a12, s}, {a21,a22, -s},{t,s,-t}} and I want to keep only the s and t symbols ...*

`Replace` and `ReplaceAll` can be used to deal with this case:

```
mat2 = {{a11, a12, s}, {a21, a22, -s}, {t, s, -t}};

Replace[#, Except[s | t | Times[_, s | t]] :> 0, {2}] & @ mat2
```

> {{0, 0, s}, {0, 0, -s}, {t, s, -t}}

```
mat2 /. Except[s | t | Times | List, _Symbol] :> 0
```

> {{0, 0, s}, {0, 0, -s}, {t, s, -t}}

Comment: Can this method be generalised to a matrix made of mixed symbols: e.g. {{a11, a12, s}, {a21,a22, -s},{t,s,-t}} and I want to keep only the s and t symbols and remove all the a_{ij}?

Comment: oh man you already did `ArrayComponents`?  So much for my contribution. :^)

Comment: @Galuoises, updated with how the case in your comment can be handled with `Replace` and `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

Or:

```
mat={{0,a,b},{c,0,d},{0,0,e}};

Map[If[#===0,1,0]&, mat, {2}]
```

(* {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{1,1,0}} *)

Answer (score 5):

```
mat = {{0, a, b}, {c, 0, d}, {0, 0, e}};

1 - mat/(mat /. 0 -> 1)
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}
> ```

Comment: Very amusing, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If the OP will accept a SparseArray:

```
SparseArray[Position[mat, 0] -> 1, Length@mat] // Normal
```

> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}

Answer (score 1):

```
ReplacePart[mat, {Position[mat, Except[List, _Symbol]] -> 0, Position[mat, 0] -> 1}]
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}} *)
```